# I want to remove /http://ditinteractive.com/company from google analytics report

Tags: google-analytics

There are multiple URL in Google Analytics report.

E.g

/http://example.com/company

/company

Above both pages are same so i want to get just only /company in stead of /http://ditinteractive.com/company.

Any body have solution then please help me to fix this.

Thanks,

Comment: Voting to close since this is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

You must have a filter applied that shows the URL instead of the URI in reports. This is how to [create a filter to show the URL instead of URI](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en).

In order to just show the URI, you'll need to disable this filter by going to:

1. *Admin*
2. *All Filters* (under Account)
3. Find the filter and delete

This will affect your data going forward and doesn't clean up your data retrospectively.